# How to validate my password using a regex in Javascript - code attached evaluates to false everytime

Tags: javascript, regex, dom-events

I have the code below and it evaluates to false every time and I don't understand why?

Is this a rookie error on my part? (I'm guessing it must be!) I'm typing a password into the password field on my form every time that starts with 1 uppercase letter, followed by 5 lowercase letters and 2 digits.

I want to regex to test for:

- At least 1 uppercase letter
- At least 1 lower case letter
- At least 1 numerical digit

I've tried editing the regex to take away the start and end anchors and have tried lazy and non lazy matching.

I also originally had the function as a function statement outside the anonymous function block and called it from within the anon function.

This is the html for the form:

```
       <form>
        <p>Username:</p>
        <input
          id="userName"
          type="text"
          required
          name="username"
          placeholder="Username"
        />
        <p>Password:</p>
        <input
          id="userPassword"
          type="password"
          required
          name="password"
          placeholder="Password"
        />
        <a href="#">Forgetten Password?</a>
        <input id="submit_btn" type="submit" name="submit_btn" />
      </form>
```

```
    //This is the JS

    const validateContainer = {
      id: [],
      username: [],
      password: []
    };

    document.getElementById("submit_btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
      let passwordInput = document.getElementById("userPassword").value; 
      let passwordRegexp = /^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{6,}$/;
      let passwordTest = passwordRegexp.test(passwordInput);

      if (passwordTest) {
        alert("Thank you");
        validateContainer.password.push(passwordInput);
      } else {
        alert("Please re-enter password");
      }
      console.log(passwordTest);
      console.log("Button was clicked");
    });
```

I'm expecting the first branch of the if statement to execute, but keep getting the else alter message and console.log(passwordTest) prints false everytime.

Comment: It works for me when I enter `1 uppercase letter, followed by 5 lowercase letters and 2 digits`. I see `Thank you`. Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I did and have no error messages. Just seems to be evaluating to false each time.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/wmn41ra9/

Comment: @Thefourthbird it seems to have worked for some reason. I deleted all my code and copy and pasted yours from the jsfiddle file. I know it was just a copy and paste of my original code, but seems to have sorted the problem for some reason! Thanks for the response, not sure how it fixed it, but it did!